# Running php file in terminal doesn't look in global-lib

Tags: php

I'm new to a codebase and trying to work out what's going on. I am trying to test a file in my terminal by doing php file-name. However some of the file includes don't specify a path eg. include_once('globalFunctions.php'). All of the files being included like this are located in a global-lib folder, however it's not looking there when running the file from the terminal. Any included file in global-lib is throwing a warning 'No such file or directory'.

Comment: Set an include path using [set_​include_​path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php)? Would that work?

Comment: Yes that fixed the problem of not finding global-lib, thanks!